# Modifying Workflows in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

Can subscriber Add actions to, or modify the actions of a workflow in an installed managed package?

Comment: Actions can be added and modified partially (f.e. for email -- change user or template), but not removed. I can not find documentation but I have just tried inside my dev environment.

Comment: @kurunve I couldn't specific documentation either.  Did you try it in a 'Managed' package instead of an Un-Managed package?

Comment: yes, I did that for 2 different managed packages

Comment: @kurunve  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Subscribers can add workflow actions but not modify existing actions or remove them.

Packaged workflows or field updates themselves cannot be edited with very few exceptions like Email Address. They can be deactivated though.

From the in-org help:

[image]